# Transforming Dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have a large csv file in which relevant dates are categorical and formatted in one column as follows: "Thu, 21 Jan 2012 04:59:00 -0000". I am trying to use as.Date, but it doesn't seem to be working. It would be create to have several columns for weekday, day, month, year, but I am happy to settle for one column at this point. Any suggestions?

UPDATE QUESTION:  Each row has a different date in the above format (weekday, day, month, year, hour, minutes, seconds. I did not make that clear. How do I transform each date in the column?

Comment: Please `dput()` sample data in the future.

Comment: `as.POSIXct("Thu, 21 Jan 2012 04:59:00 -0000", format = '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z', tz = 'UTC')`

Comment: I am new around here. by dput(), do you mean this: ("Wed, 31 Mar 2010 23:22:00 -0000"), class = "factor")

Comment: Whoa. as.POSIXct is amazing. I transformed it in seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package can parse this *without a format*:

```
R> anytime("Thu, 21 Jan 2012 04:59:00 -0000")
[1] "2012-01-21 04:59:00 CST"
R>
```

It returns a `POSIXct` you can then operate on, or just `format()`, at will.  It also has a simpler variant `anydate()` which returns a `Date` object instead.

Comment: Thanks. In your opinion, what's easier for performing data analysis on dates, a date format or POSIXct?

Comment: Different types for different uses; they are complements, not alternatives.  Most of us use both,

Comment: What I want to do is figure out the date that has the best outcome. Ideally I would like to figure out the month, or even create new variables for the season. Any suggestions?

Comment: Convert the `POSIXct` you get from `anytime()` via `as.POSIXlt()` to the latter, access the month field. Done.  Automatically vectorised.  Works for all components.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(lubridate)

my_date <- "Thu, 21 Jan 2012 04:59:00 -0000"

# Get it into date format
my_date <- dmy_hms(my_date)

# Use convenience functions to set up the columns you wanted
data.frame(day=day(my_date), month=month(my_date), year=year(my_date),
           timestamp = my_date)
```

> ```
>   day month year           timestamp
> 1  21     1 2012 2012-01-21 04:59:00
> ```

Comment: Will this transform every row?

Comment: Thank you! I played around with it and I was able to create new columns by using your code and doing the following: df$year<-data.frame(year=year(my_date)) ...etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
as.Date(str1, "%a, %d %b %Y")
#[1] "2012-01-21"
```

If we need `DateTime` format

```
v1 <- strptime(str1, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z', tz = "UTC")
v1
#[1] "2012-01-21 04:59:00 UTC"
```

Or using  `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
dmy_hms(str1)
#[1] "2012-01-21 04:59:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "Thu, 21 Jan 2012 04:59:00 -0000"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the separation in components then start with Dirk's powerful suggestion and then transpose the output of `as.POSIXlt`:

```
library(anytime)
times <- c("2004-03-21 12:45:33.123456", # example from ?anytime
          "2004/03/21 12:45:33.123456",
          "20040321 124533.123456",
          "03/21/2004 12:45:33.123456",
          "03-21-2004 12:45:33.123456",
          "2004-03-21",
          "20040321",
          "03/21/2004",
          "03-21-2004",
          "20010101")
    t( sapply( anytime::anytime(times), 
                     function(x) unlist( as.POSIXlt(x)) ) )

      sec                min  hour mday mon year  wday yday  isdst
 [1,] "33.1234560012817" "45" "12" "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [2,] "33.1234560012817" "45" "12" "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [3,] "33.1234560012817" "45" "12" "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [4,] "33.1234560012817" "45" "12" "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [5,] "33.1234560012817" "45" "12" "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [6,] "0"                "0"  "0"  "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [7,] "0"                "0"  "0"  "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [8,] "0"                "0"  "0"  "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
 [9,] "0"                "0"  "0"  "21" "2" "104" "0"  "80"  "0"  
[10,] "0"                "0"  "0"  "1"  "9" "101" "1"  "273" "1"  
      zone  gmtoff  
 [1,] "PST" "-28800"
 [2,] "PST" "-28800"
 [3,] "PST" "-28800"
 [4,] "PST" "-28800"
 [5,] "PST" "-28800"
 [6,] "PST" "-28800"
 [7,] "PST" "-28800"
 [8,] "PST" "-28800"
 [9,] "PST" "-28800"
[10,] "PDT" "-25200"
```

Comment: Wow. So I am trying to do this with what I have already transformed using Dirk's advice. So for anytime() I just put in the as.posixlt() column name?

Comment: It would need to be `as.POSIXlt`, since R is exceedingly rigorous on correct spelling, but otherwise, yes, as long as the argument is one of an R datetime, Date value or a character value that can be coerced.

Comment: How do I turn each into separate columns?

Comment: It appears your question has been answered. This appears to be both unclear (since these are "separate columns" and not related to the original question.

Comment: My original question is definitely answered.